# How can I get an asp.net mvc action to consistently deliver a file to the browser?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm building a little action to take an encrypted PDF file path, decrypt it, and deliver the resulting PDF to the browser.

My code works 100% of the time in Chrome and Firefox, but it works only 50% of the time in IE9.

When I follow the link in IE9, it looks like it opens the Adobe Reader plugin in the browser window, but no file is displayed until I hit refresh.

Here is my code:

```
    [CheckSubscriber]
    public ActionResult file(string path)
    {
        string mappedPath = Server.MapPath(
                                EncryptDecrypt.Decrypt(path,
                                EncString));

        return base.File(mappedPath, "application/pdf");

    }
```

How would I get this to work consistently in IE9?

I'm just thinking out loud here but maybe I am using the wrong mime-type?

Comment: What is the CheckSubscriber attribute doing? Does it mess with the response at all (Redirects, etc.)?

Comment: `[CheckSubscriber]` executes before the action does. It makes sure that the user is an active subscriber before allowing the action to execute. It's functionality has been tested and the action works the same with or without that attribute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be explicitly setting

```
Content-Disposition: inline; filename="foo.pdf"
```

The **content-disposition** is  a crucial response header when returning a response from the server. All browsers will correctly detect the file 100% of the time if this is specified along with the MIME type.

You can use Fiddler to ensure that the response headers are in order.

**Edit**

You cannot use the "ActionResult" return type for your action to do this.

You need to use "FilePathResult" or "FileStreamResult" both of which can be found in the System.Web.MVC namespace.

Alternatively you can create a [Custom Action Return Type](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/05/10/writing-a-custom-file-download-action-result-for-asp.net-mvc.aspx) and use that for this action.
The article I have provided gives step by step along with code as to how to go about doing this.

Comment: I don't see a parameter for Content-Disposition. how would I set that using `return base.File(.....)`?

Comment: There is an overload to File Result that takes the filename to download as the third parameter. This sets the content-disposition header for you.

Comment: @quakkels: I have edited the answer to include the options you have when going about doing this. Hope if helps. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks, as I played around with the options here, I did get the download to work. But I don't want it to download and display in a different window. I want it to be handeled by the browser by displaying in the browser window with the acrobat reader plugin.

Comment: @quakkels: You can refer to [this link](http://www.iana.org/assignments/mail-cont-disp/mail-cont-disp.xml) for a list of allowed values. For what you want, you should set the content-disposition value to "inline"

Answer (score 0):

I would use Fiddler to see the difference between the request/response that the browsers send/receive and see if you can spot it from there.

Comment: [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) is a Web Debugging Tool. It allows you to monitor all requests in and out of your webpage - a must have when working with MVC frameworks, especially if using AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I return an Excel file (pdf should be the same):

```
    public FileResult DownloadErrors(string filename)
    {
        var file = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(filename);

        return File(new System.Text.UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(file), "application/ms-excel", "Errors.csv");
    }
```

Be sure to use FileResult instead of ActionResult.